# MongoDB - The path must exist in the document

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query:

```
{ '$pull': { 'projects.$[].users': { user_id: user_id } } }
```

That fails with an error if there's no 'projects' key:

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: The path 'projects' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates.
```

Can i somehow change it so the query would just do nothing in that case?
Thanks!

Comment: you can check in query part `{projects: {$exists: true}}`

Comment: @turivishal how do i add that to the actual query?

Comment: you can do this way `update({projects: {$exists: true}}, { '$pull': { 'projects.$[].users': { user_id: user_id } } })`